# Variance definition notation question

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, variance

I have a question on the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance) definition of Variance.  Does this form represent abuse of notation or am I interpreting it incorrectly?

The definition:
$$
Var(X) = E[(X - E[X])^2]
$$
and
$$
E[X] = \sum_{i=1}^k c_i p_x(c_i) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} c p_x(c) dc
$$

It's my understanding that the parameter of $Var$ and $E$ is identified by a random variable $X$ and the result is a value of the random variable, typically $\in \mathbb{R}$.  It seems that the outermost $E$ is given some number other than the symbol for the random variable.  I'm also confused by $X - E[X]$, where $X$ appears to be a random variable subtracted by a value $\in \mathbb{R}$.

Appreciate your guidance.

Comment: E is the expectation (expected value) of X.

Comment: The expression $X - E[X]$ should be interpreted as "value of the random variable $X$ minus the constant $E[X]$". If you want this more formally, interpret $E[X]$ as a random variable with constant value $E[X]$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$E[X] = \int x f_X(x) \ dx$ is the expected value of $X$.

You have to imagine that $X$ is a function (it is indeed a function) so what $X-E[X]$ means is just a function minus a real value (which is a function).
For example, if $f(x) = x^2$ you understand what is $f(x) - 2$.

But what you have inside the variance, is taking the expectation of that "function":

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
Var[X] & =E[(X-E[X])^2]=E[X^2 - 2 X E[X] - E[X]^2] \\
& = E[X^2] - 2E[X]^2+E[X]^2 = E[X^2]-E[X]^2.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
$$$$

If you want to understand everything, you first need to know what a random variable is.
It is a function $$X: \Omega \to E$$ (where usually $E = \mathbb{R}$) with some properties.
So for example, if you consider $E = \mathbb{R}$, when you write $P(X =2)$, this is an abuse of notation for
$$P(\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) = 2\})$$
where $P$ is a probability measure and in that case the expectation would be written as
$$E[X] = \int_{\Omega} X(w) P(d \omega) = \int_{\Omega} X(w) dP$$

If you want to understand this terms better, I suggest for example that you see the [definition of random variable in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Definition).

Comment: I understand your later comment and have read through that already.  I think your first part makes sense and I'm looking at it.

Comment: I think $E[X] = \int_{\mathbb{R}} a f_X(a) da$ from what I read

Comment: yes, sorry (I edited it now)

Comment: So this can also be written, $Var(X) = \int a f_{(X-E[X])^2}(a) da$.  Treat $X$ as a function and the subtraction, exponentiation forms a new function.  It looks like this describes the expected squared deviation from the mean of $X$s values and I think I understand this now.

Comment: Correct, if you wish to see it that way, the variance is the expected value of the r.v. $Y = (X-E[X])^2$.

Comment: I think you mean $\sigma^2 = Var(X) = E[(X-E[X])]^2$?

Comment: No, the square is inside the expectation.

Comment: $E[(X - E[X])^2]$  thanks!